# Javascript - how to change color with more elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.tab{border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
           <div class="img">
              <button>HOVER</button>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
              <p>Byt 3+kk s parkovacím stáním</p>
              <p>PARDUBICE</p>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
           <div class="img">
              <button>HOVER</button>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
              <p>Byt 3+kk s parkovacím stáním</p>
              <p>PARDUBICE</p>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
           <div class="img">
              <button>HOVER</button>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
              <p>Byt 3+kk s parkovacím stáním</p>
              <p>PARDUBICE</p>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Ok i hope this html is ok. What i want is that if i hover a button, the color of "text" will change but just in div "tab" where the text is.

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Your new HTML is invalid. If you were to run your code through an html validator you would get `Error: The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element.` You should not have a clickable element inside of a clickable element.

Answer (score 0):

the div you want to change color is the sibling of the div with class = 'img'.  use .img:hover + div{ to target in your css  or remove the <div class='img' and target button:hover + div{

```css
.tab {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button:hover {
  color: red;
}

.img:hover + div {
  color: blue;
}

button:hover + div{
color:green;}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <div class='img'>
    <button>HOVER</button>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>test1yt 3+kk s parkovacím stáním</p>
    <p>PARDUBICE</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">

  
    <button>HOVER</button>
 
  <div class="text">
    <p>test 2Byt 3+kk s parkovacím stáním</p>
    <p>PARDUBICE</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <div class='img'>
    <button>HOVER</button>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>test 3Byt 3+kk s parkovacím stáním</p>
    <p>PARDUBICE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```